# costmap static_map

Tags: ros, navigation, costmap, static-map, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i have a little problem, if my localcostmap.yaml set's

```
static_map:true
rolling_window:false
```

my costmap works. but i wanna us it as a rolling window, so when i change the confoig to :

```
static_map:false
rolling_window:true
```

the map does not display anything in rviz, are there additional parameters which i need to set or change if i use the rolling_window ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39858/costmap-static_map/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-07-26**:
What do you mean by "the map does not display anything"? The costmap isn't registering obstacles?

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-26**:
yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have to make sure that you also set the size of the rolling window appropriately:

```
rolling_window: true
width: 15.0
height: 15.0
resolution: 0.05
origin_x: 0.0
origin_y: 0.0
```

When using a static map, the width and height are determined using the loaded image. In a rolling window, you must manually specify these parameters for your robot. Just know that it places your robot in the center of the rolling window, so the robot can only see things that are `height/2` meters away.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2